# Writing ASCII to file

Tags: c++, ascii, fstream

I've been thinking about an easy way for a programmer to write down all ASCII characters. First I tried to print it in a console but it didn't show me all characters. So I tried to write it to a file which worked first but now doesn't.

Code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    fstream file;
    file.open("/home/david/Desktop/ascii.txt", ios_base::out);
    for(int i = 0; i <= 255; i++)
        file << char(i);
    file.close();
    return 0;
}
```

The normal ASCII Table has 128 and the extend Table has 127. So together there are 255 characters. But somehow it doesn't save all characters to the file. Also sometimes "gedit" doesn't even recognize the encoding standard.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to open the file in binary mode.

Comment: I would guess it _is_ saving all the characters to the file, and your editor "gedit" isn't displaying them. (And it _shouldn't_ display them all.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not every ASCII character is in fact printable. For example, how would you expect a “carriage return” or “start of heading” to be displayed? Those characters could be displayed differently by different editors/terminals, or not displayed at all. It is not clear what exactly you are trying to do and why, but if you are looking for an ASCII table, [here is one](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ascii.7.html) for you:

```
       Oct   Dec   Hex   Char                        Oct   Dec   Hex   Char
       ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       000   0     00    NUL '\0'                    100   64    40    @
       001   1     01    SOH (start of heading)      101   65    41    A
       002   2     02    STX (start of text)         102   66    42    B
       003   3     03    ETX (end of text)           103   67    43    C
       004   4     04    EOT (end of transmission)   104   68    44    D
       005   5     05    ENQ (enquiry)               105   69    45    E
       006   6     06    ACK (acknowledge)           106   70    46    F
       007   7     07    BEL '\a' (bell)             107   71    47    G
       010   8     08    BS  '\b' (backspace)        110   72    48    H
       011   9     09    HT  '\t' (horizontal tab)   111   73    49    I
       012   10    0A    LF  '\n' (new line)         112   74    4A    J
       013   11    0B    VT  '\v' (vertical tab)     113   75    4B    K
       014   12    0C    FF  '\f' (form feed)        114   76    4C    L
       015   13    0D    CR  '\r' (carriage ret)     115   77    4D    M
       016   14    0E    SO  (shift out)             116   78    4E    N
       017   15    0F    SI  (shift in)              117   79    4F    O
       020   16    10    DLE (data link escape)      120   80    50    P
       021   17    11    DC1 (device control 1)      121   81    51    Q
       022   18    12    DC2 (device control 2)      122   82    52    R
       023   19    13    DC3 (device control 3)      123   83    53    S
       024   20    14    DC4 (device control 4)      124   84    54    T
       025   21    15    NAK (negative ack.)         125   85    55    U
       026   22    16    SYN (synchronous idle)      126   86    56    V
       027   23    17    ETB (end of trans. blk)     127   87    57    W
       030   24    18    CAN (cancel)                130   88    58    X
       031   25    19    EM  (end of medium)         131   89    59    Y
       032   26    1A    SUB (substitute)            132   90    5A    Z
       033   27    1B    ESC (escape)                133   91    5B    [
       034   28    1C    FS  (file separator)        134   92    5C    \  '\\'
       035   29    1D    GS  (group separator)       135   93    5D    ]
       036   30    1E    RS  (record separator)      136   94    5E    ^
       037   31    1F    US  (unit separator)        137   95    5F    _
       040   32    20    SPACE                       140   96    60    `
       041   33    21    !                           141   97    61    a
       042   34    22    "                           142   98    62    b
       043   35    23    #                           143   99    63    c
       044   36    24    $                           144   100   64    d
       045   37    25    %                           145   101   65    e
       046   38    26    &                           146   102   66    f
       047   39    27    '                           147   103   67    g
       050   40    28    (                           150   104   68    h
       051   41    29    )                           151   105   69    i
       052   42    2A    *                           152   106   6A    j
       053   43    2B    +                           153   107   6B    k
       054   44    2C    ,                           154   108   6C    l

       055   45    2D    -                           155   109   6D    m
       056   46    2E    .                           156   110   6E    n
       057   47    2F    /                           157   111   6F    o
       060   48    30    0                           160   112   70    p
       061   49    31    1                           161   113   71    q
       062   50    32    2                           162   114   72    r
       063   51    33    3                           163   115   73    s
       064   52    34    4                           164   116   74    t
       065   53    35    5                           165   117   75    u
       066   54    36    6                           166   118   76    v
       067   55    37    7                           167   119   77    w
       070   56    38    8                           170   120   78    x
       071   57    39    9                           171   121   79    y
       072   58    3A    :                           172   122   7A    z
       073   59    3B    ;                           173   123   7B    {
       074   60    3C    <                           174   124   7C    |
       075   61    3D    =                           175   125   7D    }
       076   62    3E    >                           176   126   7E    ~
       077   63    3F    ?                           177   127   7F    DEL
```

And if you are looking for a method to write ASCII characters in binary form, then you need to open your file in binary mode by setting [`std::ios_base::binary`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode) bit in open mode.

Comment: I have an ASCII Table on my Desk, but I just wanted to try to print them :P But now I know better, thanks. I'm gonna accept this question in 7 minutes.

Comment: @Davlog: You might want to give others a chance to provide a better answer, so never rush with acceptable :)

Answer (score 3):

Not all characters are printable.  You could use isprint() to check if a character is printable; if not you have to print another (ex. '.') char:
file << ((isprint(i))? char(i) : '.');

Answer (score 3):

This code will show you the printable characters:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<string>

int main() {
  std::cout<<std::setw(3)<<"dec "
           <<std::setw(3)<<"oct "
           <<std::setw(3)<<"hex "
           <<std::setw(3)<<"chr"
           <<std::endl;
  for(unsigned int id=0; id<255; id++) {
    char c = char(id);
    if(std::isprint(c)){
      std::cout<<std::dec<<std::setw(3)<<id<<" "
               <<std::oct<<std::setw(3)<<id<<" "
               <<std::hex<<std::setw(3)<<id<<" "
               <<std::setw(3)<<c<<std::endl;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
dec oct hex chr
 32  40  20    
 33  41  21   !
 34  42  22   "
 35  43  23   #
 36  44  24   $
 37  45  25   %
 38  46  26   &
 39  47  27   '
 40  50  28   (
 41  51  29   )
 42  52  2a   *
 43  53  2b   +
 44  54  2c   ,
 45  55  2d   -
 46  56  2e   .
 47  57  2f   /
 48  60  30   0
 49  61  31   1
 50  62  32   2
 51  63  33   3
 52  64  34   4
 53  65  35   5
 54  66  36   6
 55  67  37   7
 56  70  38   8
 57  71  39   9
 58  72  3a   :
 59  73  3b   ;
 60  74  3c   <
 61  75  3d   =
 62  76  3e   >
 63  77  3f   ?
 64 100  40   @
 65 101  41   A
 66 102  42   B
 67 103  43   C
 68 104  44   D
 69 105  45   E
 70 106  46   F
 71 107  47   G
 72 110  48   H
 73 111  49   I
 74 112  4a   J
 75 113  4b   K
 76 114  4c   L
 77 115  4d   M
 78 116  4e   N
 79 117  4f   O
 80 120  50   P
 81 121  51   Q
 82 122  52   R
 83 123  53   S
 84 124  54   T
 85 125  55   U
 86 126  56   V
 87 127  57   W
 88 130  58   X
 89 131  59   Y
 90 132  5a   Z
 91 133  5b   [
 92 134  5c   \
 93 135  5d   ]
 94 136  5e   ^
 95 137  5f   _
 96 140  60   `
 97 141  61   a
 98 142  62   b
 99 143  63   c
100 144  64   d
101 145  65   e
102 146  66   f
103 147  67   g
104 150  68   h
105 151  69   i
106 152  6a   j
107 153  6b   k
108 154  6c   l
109 155  6d   m
110 156  6e   n
111 157  6f   o
112 160  70   p
113 161  71   q
114 162  72   r
115 163  73   s
116 164  74   t
117 165  75   u
118 166  76   v
119 167  77   w
120 170  78   x
121 171  79   y
122 172  7a   z
123 173  7b   {
124 174  7c   |
125 175  7d   }
126 176  7e   ~
```

Answer (score 2):

For reference, see [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii) and [Extended ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII).

> RE: Also sometimes "gedit" doesn't even recognize the encoding standard.

I also highly recommend [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

From the above article, in particular note the following which is relevant to your question:

> In the ANSI standard, everybody agreed on what to do below 128, which
>   was pretty much the same as ASCII, but there were lots of different
>   ways to handle the characters from 128 and on up, depending on where
>   you lived. These different systems were called [code pages](http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/codepages.html#msftdos).

So, how the characters from 128 through 255 are portrayed in an application such as `gedit` entirely depends on what code page is active. Perhaps it's one of these two:

> Some popular encodings of English text are Windows-1252 (the Windows
>   9x standard for Western European languages) and [ISO-8859-1](http://www.htmlhelp.com/reference/charset/), aka
>   Latin-1 (also useful for any Western European language).

Also, please keep in mind that most modern applications have moved away from code pages altogether in favor of [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode). The most commonly used encodings for Unicode are [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) and [UTF-16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16). Therefore, it is possible that `gedit` supports Unicode as well. From the ASCII link above:

> To allow backward compatibility, the 128 ASCII and 256 ISO-8859-1
>   (Latin 1) characters are assigned Unicode/UCS code points that are the
>   same as their codes in the earlier standards. Therefore, ASCII can be
>   considered a 7-bit encoding scheme for a very small subset of
>   Unicode/UCS, and ASCII (when prefixed with 0 as the eighth bit) is
>   valid UTF-8.